# FastAPI и POSTMAN

Tags: postman, fastapi

Проблема подружить FastAPI и Postman  при выгрузке файлов. В ФастАпи картинки и другие файлы скачиваются без проблема, однако через Постман не получается, выходит ошибка
STATUS 422 Unprocessable Entity

```
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "loc": [
                "body",
                "file"
            ],
            "msg": "field required",
            "type": "value_error.missing"
        }
    ]
}
```

Первый код на единичный файл, второй на много сразу

```
#FastAPI how to upload files
@app.post("/upload")
async def single(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    with open(f'{file.filename}', "wb") as buffer:
        shutil.copyfileobj(file.file, buffer)
    return {"file_name": file.filename}
#FastAPI how to upload files

#FastAPI how to upload multiple files
@app.post("/img")
async def upload_images(files: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    for file in files:
        with open(f'{file.filename}', "wb") as buffer:
            shutil.copyfileobj(file.file, buffer)
    
    return {"file_name": file.filename}
#FastAPI how to upload multiple files
```

Comment: Нужно смотреть как именно запрос отправляете, и как метод в коде объявлен. Судя по ошибке, у вас файл не прикреплен.

Comment: Запрос идет методом POST. И какой файл нужно прикрепить?

Comment: Тот который вам нужно загрузить на сервис, который вы реализуете. В Postman по идее во вкладке body - выбрать тип binary, там выбрать файл через Select file.

Comment: В Headers я выбираю Content-type - application/pdf, далее в Body - form-data, там выбираю KEY - FILE, Value - добавляю нужную мне картинку.
 Да и в этом параграфе, при наведение мышкой, я получаю вот такое сообщение " This file isn't in your working directory. Teammates you share this request with won't be able to use this file. To make collaboration easier you can setup your working directory in Settings."

Comment: В binary не работает, выходит ошибка "This file isn't in your working directory. Teammates you share this request with won't be able to use this file. To make collaboration easier you can setup your working directory in Settings."

Comment: `This file isn't in your working directory. Teammates you share this request with won't be able to use this file. To make collaboration easier you can setup your working directory in Settings.` - значит так сделайте, как написано в этом сообщении: настройте рабочую директорию, положите туда ваш файл, и прикрепляйте его.

Comment: Ну ок, с рабочей директорией я решил. Но файл не отправляется, все по-старому.